# How do I calculate the output of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current-measurement

I have built this circuit to measure the current using a current transformer. I know the circuit works because I have built and tested it.

However, I'm not able to find the theoretical relationship between the input and output. The current source in the diagram represents CT. Can anyone explain the circuit mathematically? The frequency of the current is 50 Hz.

[image]

Comment: R1 & R5-C1 make a DC "center point" (needed for unipolar power supply). Then just apply the classical formula for "inverter" with an input voltage equal to I1*R4.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you designed and built this circuit having no idea of how it would work? This smells like homework to me. If not, where did you find the circuit? How did you select the component values?

Comment: Hint: The voltage at the non-inverting input of the op-amp cannot be assumed to be constant with a 50Hz input.

Comment: This is not homework. The based of the value of capacitor and R1, R5 the output changes. The with smaller capacitor value, signal amplitude is reduced. And with large value of R1 and R5 noise increases a lot. So I was trying to figure out the frequency response.

Comment: When I use 1k as R1 and R5, output gets more smooth. So the frequency response is changing with these values I guess.

Comment: And the coil of CT is part of the system.

Comment: C1 should be "bigger" so that voltage at the (+) input should be more "constant".

Comment: Yes, the circuit shown has higher gain for higher frequencies, which is probably the opposite of what you want (some kind of LPF action).

Comment: Personally, I would consider moving the input (R4/I1) to the non-inverting side.

Comment: If you have built this circuit, it is easier to simulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your graphs show potentials at the inverting input, and one side of C2 (not clear which side). Neither of these values really represents an "input" of any kind, because the voltage at the non-inverting input will also vary in this setup.

What is the input? I would have thought current \$I_1\$ was the input, and the potential at the op-amp's output (call it \$V_{OUT}\$) was the output. In that case this would have gain \$\frac{V_{OUT}}{I_1}\$, with units \$\frac{V}{A} = \Omega\$ making this a transimpedance amplifier.

What makes this circuit difficult (well, less trivial) to analyse is the strange configuration at the non-inverting input, which is clearly an attempt to bias the output half way between the power rails. It suffers from the fact that any potential difference across R4 is going to influence the potentials at both the left end of R6 and also the non-inverting input, and so we can't apply a simple inverting or non-inverting amplifier equation to this setup. This will require a more complete analysis. I don't doubt that it works, or that it's linear.

I don't know if what follows is the best way to analyse the circuit, but it's what I came up with. I'm going to ignore C2, which has a few hundred ohms impedance at 50Hz, small compared to the peripheral resistors.

I should point out that I'm also thinking that the average DC voltage across C2 is zero. If I'm wrong about that, then my analysis will show an incorrect output offset, but the presence or absence of C2 shouldn't affect gain, which is what you asked for. We'll see, I suppose.

C1 doesn't really feature in the analysis because its purpose is clearly to suppress higher frequency components.

Next I'm going to try to simplify the biasing network consisting of a +3V source, R1 and R5, by replacing it all with the Thevenin equivalent.

As a further simplification, I'm going to assume that current \$I_1\$ in the current transformer is routed entirely through R4, which is tiny compared to the paths its connected to. Only negligible current will leave that loop, and the combination of source I1 and R4 form a negligibly low impedance (10Ω) voltage source, which I will call \$V_{IN}\$ and treat as the input to the system.

What we are left with is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4hDij.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My claim that the potential at Q will vary can be seen with a quick simulation:

[image]

In a standard inverting amplifier configuration, we could guess that gain is \$-\frac{R_7}{R_6} = -1\$, but we would be wrong. Sure, there is negative feedback here which makes this *look* like a standard inverting amplifier, but there is also an element of positive feedback, since as \$V_{OUT}\$ varies, so does \$V_Q\$. That's obvious now, because current through R6 and R7 also flows through Rth.

In fact, this circuit more closely resembles a non-inverting configuration, with the complication of that voltage source VIN in the feedback loop. I'm not sure off the top of my head how to deal with that, so I'll have to resort to a nodal analysis.

Our first equation comes from the behaviour of an op-amp with negative feedback. It will always raise or lower its output such that its non-inverting and inverting inputs have the same potential:

$$V_P = V_Q$$

Since the op-amp has high input impedance, current into or out of its inputs is negligible, and we can see that there's a single current path between OUT and the 1.5V Thevenin source. That current flows via R7, R6 and Rth. We can combine KVL and Ohm's law in one equation:

$$ 1.5 + IR_{TH} + V_{IN} + IR_6 + IR_7 = V_{OUT} $$

Since \$V_P = V_Q\$, we can also travel from node Q to P, knowing that we will have traversed a net potential difference of 0V:

$$ V_{IN} + IR_6 = V_P - V_Q = 0 $$

I'll not reproduce the algebra I did on paper here, you can solve those last two simultaneous equations yourself. I got this relationship between \$V_{OUT}\$ and \$V_{IN}\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= -V_{IN}\left(\frac{R_{TH}+R_7}{R_6}\right) + 1.5 \\ \\
&= 1.5V_{IN} + 1.5
\end{aligned}
$$

I've just realised that (by happy accident) the graph I plotted above happens to closely match your own graph, assuming that \$V_{IN}\$ is a sinusoid of 1V peak-to-peak. That would correspond to a current from your transformer of 100mA peak-to-peak (through 10Ω). Is that the correct current for the source I1 in your simulation?

This analysis raises a few points:

- This setup is weird (the placement of the current transformer is confusing), but it works.
- Since the transformer secondary is isolated, it already has zero average voltage across it, and I don't think DC blocking with C2 is necessary.
- C1 isn't very effective in its current position. To attenuate higher frequencies, I suggest placing C1 in parallel with R7, where it will reduce overall gain at higher frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried to calculate it thinking like a simple inverting amplifier and when the oscilloscope reading didn’t match at all, I made a simulation. I found that both of the inputs are oscillating and realised my simple maths aren’t going to work. And input is exactly 100mA peak to peak in the simulation.

Comment: Sorry, It's 50mA in the simulation. And in your graph, I'm seeing It's 50 mV (1.25 to 1.75). So both are same.

Answer (score 5):

Opamp circuits are categorized into one of the following types:

- Open-loop opamps, basically comparators
- The ones with negative feedback, usually leading to some kind of analog amplifier
- The ones with positive feedback, usually leading to some kind of Schmitt-trigger

After determining which type you are dealing with, you will have to choose your strategy in solving it. Since you have built it, you already know it is of the second type as the others are digital in nature.

The strategy for opamps in negative feedback is:

$$v_{-} = v_{+}$$

Which you can add to your list of KCL equations. Combined with the opamp property that no current can go in/out the input terminals, you can simply ignore the opamp for the other KCL equations.

> Can anyone explain the circuit mathematically?

You can use sympy in Python to solve KCL equations symbolically. Please note that not many people will (want to) take the time to solve it for you.

Answer (score 3):

For analysis, pretend that the current sensor in parallel with \$R_{4}\$ is a voltage source in series with \$R_{4}\$ by performing a *source transformation*.

$$V_{\text{I}}=I_{1}R_{4}$$

This places  \$R_{4}\$, \$R_{6}\$, and \$C_{2}\$ in series thus forming the input branch of a classic inverting amplifier. So:

$$V_{\text{out}}=\frac{-R_{7}}{R_{4}+R_{6}+Z_{C_{2}}}I_{1}R_{4}\tag{1}$$

Presumably, \$C_{1}\$ is large enough to make the non-inverting input appear as ac ground.

From your comment:

> When I use 1k as R1 and R5, output gets more smooth. So the frequency response is changing with these values I guess.

This shows that the ac ground presumption is insufficient, making the analysis more complicated.

To preserve the inverting circuit and to approach the gain formula in equation (1), \$R_{1}\$ and \$R_{5}\$ must be reduced and \$C_{1}\$ increased. This results in increased biasing current.

A alternative biasing solution is to buffer the filtered voltage divider with a unity gain amplifier as shown below. The circuit will work better and make the analysis more tractable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0q1LX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$C_{2}\$ can be eliminated as @Sperho-Pefhany suggested by connecting the current sensor and \$R_{4}\$ directly to \$R_{6}\$, unless you want the low frequency roll-off.

@Antonio51's non-inverting form is worth considering. It can still benefit from the buffered bias.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As @Spehro-Pefhany pointed out, CT sensor should be on other side.
Then one capacitor may be omitted ...

And function can be simply obtained.
For current of 40 mA pp, one has 400 mV pp on R5.
Peak to peak voltage on output is 0.80 V, which leads to a "Voltage gain" of 2.
Which is obvious for this circuit, "non inverter" \$Voltage Gain = R3/R4+1 = 2\$.

[image]

Comment: I'll make this circuit tomorrow because I didn't think this way. Removing the capacitor in input will be a great benefit.